# How to perform CASE on values from subquery

Tags: sql, case

This is going to be difficult to explain, but here goes.

I am looking to perform a CASE condition in a `SELECT` clause that will use the results of two calculations to determine which calculation value to return for a column value.

Maybe a code sample will help:

this works:

```
SELECT 
   A.[COLUMN1]
   , B.[COLUMN1]
   , CASE 
      WHEN A.[COLUMN2] + A.[COLUMN3] >= B.[COLUMN2] + B.[COLUMN3] THEN A.[COLUMN2] + A.[COLUMN3]
      ELSE B.[COLUMN2] + B.[COLUMN3]
FROM
   [TABLE_A] A
      INNER JOIN [TABLE_B] B INNER JOIN ON A.ID = B.ID
```

The problem here is that the query above, in the case statement, is forced to perform the calculation twice. Once for the `WHEN` clause and again for the `THEN` clause.

I want to do something like this, but SQL is not happy with it.

```
SELECT 
   A.[COLUMN1]
   , B.[COLUMN1]
   , CASE 
      WHEN AB.X >= AB.Y THEN AB.X
      ELSE AB.Y
     END
     FROM ((A.[COLUMN2] + A.[COLUMN3]) X, (B.[COLUMN2] + B.[COLUMN3]) Y)
FROM
   [TABLE_A] A
      INNER JOIN [TABLE_B] B INNER JOIN ON A.ID = B.ID
```

Is this even possible? In the second example, I am calculating the values only once and referring to them in the case statement, both for the `WHEN` and the `THEN` clauses.

Comment: @RaphaëlAlthaus: SQL Server 2008 R2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would much prefer to push the calculations down into each table.  This keeps the structure of the query quite similar.  So, a syntactically correct (or almost correct) version would be:

```
SELECT A.[COLUMN1], B.[COLUMN1],
       (CASE WHEN a.col_2_3 >= b.col_2_3 THEN a.col_2_3
             ELSE b.col_2_3
        end)
FROM (select a.*,  (A.[COLUMN2] + A.[COLUMN3]) as col_2_3
      from [TABLE_A] a
     ) a INNER JOIN
     (select b.*, (B.[COLUMN2] + B.[COLUMN3]) as col_2_3
      from [TABLE_B] b
     )b
     ON a.ID = b.ID
```

There are so many important factors in performance, and overhead for simple calculations is just not one of them.  Reading the data and the join are way, way more expensive than simple calculations.

However, moving variables into subqueries is useful for a few reasons.  First, the calculations could be more expensive (using subqueries, say).  It also helps with readability and hence maintainability.

Finally, a SQL engine *could* decide to evaluate those expressions just once.  In practice, I'm guessing that none make that trivial optimization.

Comment: +1. I completely agree with what you are saying about performance and the triviality of the calculations. I _think_ I am more interested in the readability and maintainability of the query in the long run.

Answer (score 1):

You could reformulate it as this

```
SELECT a_column1, 
       b_column1, 
       CASE 
         WHEN x >= y THEN x 
         ELSE y 
       END AS foo 
FROM   (SELECT A.[column1]                   A_COLUMN1, 
               B.[column1]                   B_COLUMN1, 
               ( A.[column2] + A.[column3] ) X, 
               ( B.[column2] + B.[column3] ) Y 
        FROM   [table_a] A 
               INNER JOIN [table_b] B 
                       ON A.id = B.id)t
```

But I'm not sure it will make a difference since the operations may be performed once per row anyway

Comment: Ah, yes, the good ol' optimizer, which causes no end of confusion to imperative/procedural programmers - woe to them which expect short-circuit logic!  It might be good to note that, while the calculations _might_ only be performed once, certain **functions** are usually called more than once - `RANDOM()`, or an equivalent, for example

Comment: Even better, add a second call to the function, for more fun.